# Переключение раскладки в i3

Tags: linux, ubuntu, клавиатура, i3wm

я пытаюсь настроить клавиатуру в `i3` (kubuntu 22.04). Хочу переключать раскладку клавиатуры на `right control`.

Я ввожу команду в терминале:

`setxkbmap -model pc104 -layout us,ru -option grp:rctrl_toggle`

Не работает. Правильно ли я понимаю, что эта опция относится к `right control`. Команда работает с более привычными опциями: `grp:alt_shift_toggle` и `grp:caps_toggle`

Вывод команды: `setxkbmap -print -verbose 10`

```
Setting verbose level to 10
locale is C
Trying to load rules file ./rules/evdev...
Trying to load rules file /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev...
Success.
Applied rules from evdev:
rules:      evdev
model:      pc104
layout:     us,ru
options:    grp:rctrl_toggle, grp:alt_shift_toggle,grp:ctrl_alt_toggle
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwerty)
types:      complete
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+us+ru:2+inet(evdev)+group(rctrl_toggle)+group(ctrl_alt_toggle)+group(alt_shift_toggle)
geometry:   pc(pc104)
xkb_keymap {
   xkb_keycodes  { include "evdev+aliases(qwerty)"   };
   xkb_types     { include "complete"   };
   xkb_compat    { include "complete"   };
   xkb_symbols   { include "pc+us+ru:2+inet(evdev)+group(rctrl_toggle)+group(ctrl_alt_toggle)+group(alt_shift_toggle)"   };
   xkb_geometry  { include "pc(pc104)"   };
};
```

Также не работает автозапуск команды через `~/.config/i3/config`, только через терминал получается.

`exec --no-startup-id "setxkbmap -model pc104 -layout us,ru -option grp:alt_shift_toggle"`

Перепробовал все из этого [руководства](https://igancev.ru/2021-10-31-i3wm-keyboard-layout)

Comment: А зачем вы в exec обернули команду в кавычки? Во всех виденных мной инструкциях кавычек никогда не было

Comment: @andreymal, в каком-то мануале видел, но я пробовал и без)

Comment: @ИльяЯрусов, если верить выводу `setxkbmap -print`, у тебя включено переключение и по `rctrl`, и по `ctrl+alt`... видимо, второе поглощает первое и совместное использование оных невозможно... если это сделано случайно, то просто сбрось системные настройки перед установкой опций, добавив пустой параметр `-option`: `setxkbmap -model pc104 -layout us,ru -option -option grp:rctrl_toggle`

Answer (score 0):

@Fat-Zer, да это сработало!

`setxkbmap -model pc104 -layout us,ru -option -option grp:rctrl_toggle`

Но автозапуск так и не получается сделать(

Comment: я не скажу за настройку i3 — не сталкивался, но если хочешь можешь, например, это в `~/.xprofile` добавить...